# Display an textbox via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form in JavaScript and I would like to display an input box  like this:

[image]

A normal text box is displayed and using `onmouseover="catchEvent()"` and an editable pop up is displayed and its value to be used for further processing.

Is there any such pop element available?

Comment: use css :focus: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: Do you mean that a list of suggestions pops up, that if clicked by the user, are copied into the normal textbox?  I don't understand why the popup would be editable, if the text input is already editable.

Comment: @JohnV thanks for the comment.But thats just for getting the focus.My question is if there any element like pop up available.

Comment: @Paul Yes it does.But that would be the supporting information related to textbox.Like for example input textbox will contain First Name and pop up textbox will contain information 'This is first name' - to be provided by user.This is just an example

Comment: No there's no such native popup element. There are various ways of achieving this which I think you can find easily by just googling 'show popup on hover' or something similar. I think your best bet would be to go with a jquery solution.